# Issue with Oracle Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am not sure if I should have put this as an edit to my existing question but I decided against it as it was a different issue. The trigger deals with two tables: users{id, name, status} offerings{id, title, price, userid, status};

I would like that when the user table is updated an the status of a entry is change to 2 that all offerings that the user has made will be changed to i (for inactive)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_offering_status
      BEFORE UPDATE ON users
 FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.status = 'i')
BEGIN
     UPDATE offering
     SET status = 'i'
    WHERE userid = offering.userid;
END;
```

The issue is that it is changing all the offering status to i.

I believe that the problem is

```
WHERE userid = offering.userid;
```

It should be if the userid of the offering matches the userid of the user that is being updated mark as inactive. I do not know how to code this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_offering_status BEFORE UPDATE ON users
 FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.status = 'i')
BEGIN
     UPDATE offering
     SET status = 'i'
    WHERE userid = :NEW.id
END;
```

You weren't referencing any user in specific. You were updating all rows because `userid = offering.userid` is the same as doing `offering.userid = offering.userid`, and this would always be true.

Comment: It comes up as an error 'ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause'

Comment: @Vuzuggu. That was the : before the NEW.status. it shouldn't be there. i already edited the anser